# Как выбрать список checkbox через shift?

Tags: javascript, html, form

Есть список checkbox-ов, нужно передать в php диапазон от одного до другого, перечислив при этом каждый checkbox в промежутке.

Я догадываюсь, что этим должен заниматься javascript (не обязательно через shift), который мониторит выставляемые галки и сам выставляет промежутки, но можно ли это сделать элегантней?

Answer (score 1):

А как оно будет определять, пользователь хочет поставить галочку, или убрать?) И что будет, если третий клик будет вне диапазона? А если внутри? А как узнать, он вообще диапазон хочет выставить или просто выделить три блока?) Чтобы не путаться в этих вопросах, можно бы оставить чекбоксы в покое, но добавить быстрое выделение через наведение курсора с зажатой мышкой...

```js
let check = document.querySelectorAll('.check');
let lab = document.querySelectorAll('.lab');
let hover = false;
for( let i = 0; i < lab.length; i++ ){
  lab[i].addEventListener('mousedown', function(){
    hover = true;
  });
    
  lab[i].addEventListener('mousemove', function(){
    if( hover ){
      check[i].checked = true;
    }
  });
}

document.addEventListener('mouseup', function(){ hover = false; });

document.getElementById('reset').addEventListener('click', function(){
  for( let i = 0; i < check.length; i++ ){
    check[i].checked = false;
  }
});
```

```css
.lab {
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #123;
  color: white;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 180px;
  user-select: none;
}
.lab:hover {
  background-color: #48a;
}
```

```html
<input id="reset" type="button" value="Сброс">
<label class="lab"><input class="check" type="checkbox"> Текст... </label>
<label class="lab"><input class="check" type="checkbox"> Текст... </label>
<label class="lab"><input class="check" type="checkbox"> Текст... </label>
<label class="lab"><input class="check" type="checkbox"> Текст... </label>
<label class="lab"><input class="check" type="checkbox"> Текст... </label>
<label class="lab"><input class="check" type="checkbox"> Текст... </label>
<label class="lab"><input class="check" type="checkbox"> Текст... </label>
```

Comment: Полезный, информативный ответ

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function() {
  
  $('#getFeatures').click(function() {
    var features = [];
    $('.feature input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function() {
      features.push($(this).val());
    });
    $('#selectedFeatures').html(features.join(','));
    //можно передать их на сервер
    $.post('parse.php', { checked: features });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="feature">
  <h2>Features</h2>
  <label><input class="custom_css" checked="" type="checkbox" name="feature[]" value="custom_css"> Custom CSS (style.css)</label>
  <label><input class="custom_js" checked="" type="checkbox" name="feature[]" value="custom_js"> Custom Javascript (script.js)</label>
  <label><input class="modernizr" type="checkbox" name="feature[]" value="modernizr"> Modernizr</label>
  <label><input class="google_maps" type="checkbox" name="feature[]" value="google_maps"> Google Maps</label>
  <label><input class="custom_api" type="checkbox" name="feature[]" value="custom_api"> Custom API</label>
  <label><input class="font_awesome" type="checkbox" name="feature[]" value="font_awesome"> Font Awesome</label>
</div>

<button id="getFeatures">GET FEATURES</button>
<div id="selectedFeatures"></div>
```